# APEX set Style on Text Area

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Below is a field I have formatted in Oracle and we want to place it on an APEX form in a Textarea.  The data is displayed but the formatting is off.. The number are not in nice columns like below but all over the place.  I believe this has something to do with monospaced.  Basically spaces and characters do not take up the same space.  So I probably need to change the style or font on the Textarea but I have tried everything and it is just not working.  I hope someone can help.

The form is fine it is just the textarea I care about. So I don't think I want to set a style on the page properties....

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a test on APEX 19.1 and the default font for textareas was Menlo, which is a monospaced font. At any rate, if you look at your page properties for Inline under CSS. Then add something like this:

```
#P1_TEXTAREA {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

Just replace the item name with the correct name. That should do the trick.